# Export a high resolution image from ArcScene

Tags: export, resolution, arcscene

My 2D output from ArcScene is very pixelated, regardless of the export format I use. I've tried higher DPI, but that doesn't seem to help. I've tried PDF, JPEG, SVG, TIFF, .ai. They're all very pixelated. I attached an example of a 300 dpi JPEG output. Any ideas on how to adjust the settings so I can get a higher resolution? I tried zooming in and exporting, and the zoomed-in version of the layer had higher resolution. This is my first time using ArcScene so I'm not very familiar with the basics.

[image: Jpg output]

Comment: How did you configure the surface on which the scene was built?

Comment: I created a TIN using a 30-meter resolution DEM. Then I imported the TIN into ArcScene. I'm not sure if this is fully answering your question. Two other layers (bottom and top) are polygons and one is a point layer.

Comment: There's a number of controls that allow you to specify the analysis resolution. There's a memory/compute cost for increased resolution (based on a square rule -- twice the resolution costs four times as much), so you need to be very careful. It's been ages since I last used ArcScene, but setting the underlying surface is pretty fundamental, so you want to look at the properties of your scene.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Vince. I tried adjusting those rendering settings (under Layer Properties - Rendering - Optimize) and nothing changed. I also tested this with the vector layers to no avail, and they appear pixelated in the ArcScene display, even with the highest rendering settings. Maybe there is a specific location that adjusts the scene resolution properties, rather than just the layer properties? If so, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I ended up exporting 2d maps from ArcMap at high resolution, then edited the perspective in Illustrator. I never figured out how to increase the resolution from ArcScene.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Export Scene", choose export format as .tif, select the resolution you want and then on the bottom of the window change "View size" to the highest it'll let you. That should make it better...